# Describing the points of a glued topos

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Let $f : \mathbf{X}\to \mathbf{Y}$ be a morphism of topoi; in his 1977 monograph, Johnstone describes the *open mapping cylinder* of $f$ as the following pushout of topoi:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbf{X} @>{f}>> \mathbf{Y}\\
@V{\textit{closed point}}VV {\scriptsize\textit{(cocart)}}@VVV\\
\mathbf{X}\times\mathbb{S} @>>> \mathbf{M}_f^\circ
\end{CD}

Because $\mathbf{M}_f^\circ$ is defined by a pushout, it is easy to view it as a figure shape --- and in particular, it is easy to see by mapping into the "topos of sets" / object classifier $\mathbb{O}$ that the topos, viewed as a category of sheaves or "Giraud frame", is the Artin gluing of the direct image functor $f_*$. **On the other hand, it is not so clear how to understand the (generalized) *points* of $\mathbf{M}_f^\circ$, since points are described by mapping in. What exactly does $\mathbf{M}_f^\circ$ classify?**

A hint is suggested by the fact that $\mathbf{M}_f^\circ$ is a kind of generalized Sierpiński cone / scone, where instead of pushing out along the terminal map $\mathbf{X} : \mathbf{X}\to \mathbf{1}$, we push out along $f : \mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{Y}$. In the case of the actual scone $\hat{\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{M}^\circ_{\mathbf{X}}$, the points are easy to describe using the fact that the scone can be reconstructed as the restriction of the Vickers-Johnstone "lower bagdomain topos" along the inclusion $\mathbb{S}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{O}$:
\begin{CD}
\hat{\mathbf{X}} @>>> \mathbf{B}_{\mathsf{L}}(\mathbf{X})\\
@VVV {\scriptsize\textit{(cart)}} @VVV\\
\mathbb{S} @>>> \mathbb{O}
\end{CD}

**Under this identification, a point $\mathbf{W}\to \hat{\mathbf{X}}$ is determined by the data of an open $U\in \mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{W}}$ together with a point $\mathbf{W}_{/U}\to \mathbf{X}$.** This universal property, by the way, makes perfect sense if you think of the scone as a "toposification" of the *lift monad* from domain theory: a point of the scone $\hat{\mathbf{X}}$ is just a "partial point" of $\mathbf{X}$.

---

I would like to find out whether there is a similar way to understand the open mapping cylinder for an arbitrary morphism of topoi $f$, where I have a crisp description of what it classifies in the style of the above. And if this makes sense, I am also curious about the closed mapping cylinder obtained by flipping the orientation of $\mathbb{S}$ by gluing with the open point $\mathbf{X}\to\mathbf{X}\times\mathbb{S}$ instead of the closed point.

It seems like there may be a way to do it by viewing $\mathbf{X}$ in a relative style as a $\mathbf{Y}$-topos and considering the ordinary scone, but I have to admit that I am not yet skilled with using the relative point of view in the category of topoi.

Comment: It's kind of shocking -- people have been studying toposes in general and Artin glueing in particular for decades -- I'm surprised I can't find a description of what the Artin glueing classifies anywhere! Do you know the answer when, say $f$ is etale?

Comment: Following your suggestion about relativization, one would expect that it classifies something like commutative squares$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbf{W}_{/U}&\to&\mathbf{X}\\\downarrow&&\downarrow\\\mathbf{W}&\to&\mathbf{Y}\end{array}$$except that one has to take isomorphisms witnessing commutativity of these squares as part of the structure...

Comment: In other words, it should classify isomorphisms $y|_U\cong f(x)$ (for various $U\in\mathcal O_{\mathbf W}$) where $y$ is a thing in $\mathbf W$ classified by $\mathbf Y$ and $x$ is a thing in $\mathbf W_{/U}$ classified by $\mathbf X$

Comment: Matthias Hutzler has work in progress on something related: https://gitlab.com/MatthiasHu/gluing-classifying-toposes

Comment: This seems really related to what I have been working on lately! :-) I think @მამუკაჯიბლაძე 's guess is right, but I can't really see it from the definition in the question yet. In terms of geometric theories, this is what I call "conditional extension" of the theory extension classified by the X --> Y. (After adding a new proposition symbol to the theory for Y, which corresponds to the product with sierpinski topos.) I will try to answer as soon as I understand a bit more.

Comment: What a fascinating discussion! Thanks all for your contributions so far.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I was revisiting this and had the thought that with your computation, we should expect to get a geometric morphism from the glued topos into the sierpinski cone of X, but I don't see why that should be the case unless $f$ is an embedding... Are we forgetting to do something?

Comment: On the other hand, a similar observation to yours is claimed by Joyal and Moerdijk in "A completeness theorem for open maps".

Comment: P.S. Never mind about my comment about not seeing how you would get that geometric morphism --- I see it now.

Comment: Alright, so according to Joyal and Moerdijk, you that square idea of @მამუკაჯიბლაძე is almost correct, but not quite. The issue is that the point of $\mathbf{Y}$ has to be valued in the closed complement of $\mathbf{W}_U$ rather than $\mathbf{W}$. Unfortunately this seems to preclude a fully geometrical explanation, because the commutativity condition must be stated in terms of the fringe functor of $U$, which of course need not be a geometric morphism in either direction.